# Hash system to generate same (specified) hash from multiple datasets?

Tags: algorithm, security, hash

I have a hashed value X and need to ensure that any of the data sets D1...Dn can be concatenated with a correctional value C1...Cn and passed into a hashing algorithm to result in the value of X. What I need is a way to figure out what Ci should be in order to ensure that hash( Di ++ Ci ) = X. If I use a simple hash like addition or XOR then it'll be pretty easy, but is there any way to figure out Ci for better hashing algorithms?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I muight be misunderstanding your question here, but it seems to me like you're intentionally trying to defeat the purpose of most hashing algorithms (I.E you are intentionally trying to cause collisions).

Comment: If that is the case, you have to understand that any crytpto-secure hash algorithm, such as SHA256, is going to have been designed to defeat this type of abuse.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you'll probably get more answers on http://crypto.stackexchange.com/ or http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Alright then, thanks.  Though I mainly wondering if a hashing algorithm already exists that is designed for something like this.

Comment: @gankoji In a sense that's true, but the purpose is a bit different.  The completed hash X would be hidden on a server S and clients A and B both have access to it but C does not.  A and B will send their credentials Ac and Bc to S and S will generate correctional strings Ay and By such that hash(Ac + Ay ) == X and hash(Bc + By) == X but hash(Cc) != X.

Comment: @raystubbs that sounds more like salted hashes than the original question, although you specify a single hash for all authenticated users instead of a unique salted hash for each user. Not sure why you'd do it that way, especially when you consider the point about intentional collisions i mentioned earlier.

Comment: @gankoji Alright, thanks.  Just experimenting with NDN access control, I guess this method wouldn't work then.